# Some special arrangement of rows within two factors

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, data-manipulation

I want to arrange Cities within Reg in such a way that if Reg and City match then that should come at top in that Reg and remaining Cities should be arranged alphabetically in ascending order. An Extract from long required is given below.

**Required Output**

```
  Reg City   Res Pop Pop1
   A    A Total 204   19
   A    A Rural 101   10
   A    A Urban 103    9
   A    a Total 109   11
   A    a Rural  55    5
   A    a Urban  54    6
   A    b Total  95    8
   A    b Rural  46    5
   A    b Urban  49    3
   B    B Total 325   24
   B    B Rural 166   10
   B    B Urban 159   14
   B    c Total 119    7
   B    c Rural  53    0
   B    c Urban  66    7
   B    d Total 108    9
   B    d Rural  61    6
   B    d Urban  47    3
   B    e Total  98    8
   B    e Rural  52    4
   B    e Urban  46    4
```

**MWE**
MWE is below:

```
df6 <-
  structure(list(Reg = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
  1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
  "B"), class = "factor"), City = c("a", "a", "a", "A", "A", "A", 
  "b", "b", "b", "B", "B", "B", "c", "c", "c", "d", "d", "d", "e", 
  "e", "e"), Res = c("Total", "Rural", "Urban", "Total", "Rural", 
  "Urban", "Total", "Rural", "Urban", "Total", "Rural", "Urban", 
  "Total", "Rural", "Urban", "Total", "Rural", "Urban", "Total", 
  "Rural", "Urban"), Pop = c(109L, 55L, 54L, 204L, 101L, 103L, 
  95L, 46L, 49L, 325L, 166L, 159L, 119L, 53L, 66L, 108L, 61L, 47L, 
  98L, 52L, 46L), Pop1 = c(11L, 5L, 6L, 19L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 5L, 3L, 
  24L, 10L, 14L, 7L, 0L, 7L, 9L, 6L, 3L, 8L, 4L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
  -21L), .Names = c("Reg", "City", "Res", "Pop", "Pop1"))

library(dplyr)
df6 %>%
  arrange(Reg, City)
```

I guess the required output might be attained using `arrange_if` function from `dplyr` but could not figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
library(dplyr)

df6 %>%
  mutate(match.RegCity = Reg==City) %>%
  arrange(Reg,                 #arrange by Reg first
          desc(match.RegCity), # then by whether Reg==City (TRUE before FALSE)
          City) %>%            # then by City
  select(-match.RegCity)

   Reg City   Res Pop Pop1
1    A    A Total 204   19
2    A    A Rural 101   10
3    A    A Urban 103    9
4    A    a Total 109   11
5    A    a Rural  55    5
6    A    a Urban  54    6
7    A    b Total  95    8
8    A    b Rural  46    5
9    A    b Urban  49    3
10   B    B Total 325   24
11   B    B Rural 166   10
12   B    B Urban 159   14
13   B    c Total 119    7
14   B    c Rural  53    0
15   B    c Urban  66    7
16   B    d Total 108    9
17   B    d Rural  61    6
18   B    d Urban  47    3
19   B    e Total  98    8
20   B    e Rural  52    4
21   B    e Urban  46    4
```